# How to make selenium faster using asynchronous programming?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, asynchronous, web-scraping

My objective with is to scrape as many profile links as possible on Khan Academy. And then scrape some specific data on each of these profiles to write them into a CSV file.

Here is the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException,StaleElementReferenceException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming#intro-to-programming')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

#find course steps links
courses_links = soup.find_all(class_='link_1uvuyao-o_O-nodeStyle_cu2reh-o_O-nodeStyleIcon_4udnki')
list_courses={}

for links in courses_links:
    courses = links.extract()
    link_course = courses['href']
    title_course= links.find(class_='nodeTitle_145jbuf')
    span_title_course=title_course.span
    text_span=span_title_course.text.strip()
    final_link_course ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+link_course
    list_courses[text_span]=final_link_course


# my goal is to loop the below script with each "course link" that I got above with list_courses
for courses_step in list_courses.values():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(courses_step)
    while True:
        try:
            showmore=WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'button_1eqj1ga-o_O-shared_1t8r4tr-o_O-default_9fm203')))
            showmore.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            break

    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
    #find the profile links
    profiles = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("/profile/kaid"))
    profile_list=[]
    for links in profiles:
        links_no_list = links.extract()
        text_link = links_no_list['href']
        text_link_nodiscussion = text_link[:-10]
        final_profile_link ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+text_link_nodiscussion
        profile_list.append(final_profile_link)

    #remove duplicates
    profile_list=list(set(profile_list))

    #print number of profiles we got
    print('in this link:')
    print(courses_step)
    print('we have this number of profiles:')
    print(len(profile_list))

    #create the csv file
    filename = "khan_mergetry4.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w")
    headers = "link, date_joined, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx, last_date\n"
    f.write(headers)

    #for each profile link, scrape the specific data and store them into the csv
    for link in profile_list:
        
        #print each profile link we are about to scrape
        print("Scraping ",link)
        driver.get(link)

        #wait for content to load
        #if profile does not exist skip
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,'//*[@id="widget-list"]/div[1]/div[1]')))
        except TimeoutException:
            continue
        soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
        user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')
        if user_info_table is not None:
            dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]
        else:
            dates=points=videos='NA'

        user_socio_table=soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-stat')
        data = {}
        for gettext in user_socio_table:
            category = gettext.find('span')
            category_text = category.text.strip()
            number = category.previousSibling.strip()
            data[category_text] = number

        full_data_keys=['questions','votes','answers','flags raised','project help requests','project help replies','comments','tips and thanks'] #might change answers to answer because when it's 1 it's putting NA instead
        for header_value in full_data_keys:
            if header_value not in data.keys():
                data[header_value]='NA'

        user_calendar = soup.find('div',class_='streak-calendar-scroll-container')
        if user_calendar is not None:
            last_activity = user_calendar.find('span',class_='streak-cell filled')
            try:
                last_activity_date = last_activity['title']
            except TypeError:
                last_activity_date='NA'
        else:
            last_activity_date='NA'
        f.write(link + "," + dates + "," + points.replace("," , "") + "," + videos + "," + data['questions'] + "," + data['votes'] + "," + data['answers'] + "," + data['flags raised'] + "," + data['project help requests'] + "," + data['project help replies'] + "," + data['comments'] + "," + data['tips and thanks'] + "," + last_activity_date + "\n")
```

As you can see this is a synchronous version.

My problem is that this script is way too slow. (probably more than 100 hours to be fully executed).

How can I make it work faster?
How can I make this script asynchronous?
What should I use to do it?
How should I organize my code to do it?
(Maybe multiprocessing is more adapted?)

Comment: You might want to look at [using Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over. Scrapy or switch to a asynchronous language.